# XML transform in node.js using pure JS?

Tags: node.js, xslt, node-gyp

I have been trying to find a node.js based XML transform tool to replace the use of msxsl.exe or mono-xmltool.exe.

I have tried to install gulp-xslt and xsl-transform on Win8 x64 with node.js 0.12.
However both fail to install due to errors in "node_xslt" and "node-gyp".

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn C:\tools\pyhton2 ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1046:32)
gyp ERR! stack     at child_process.js:1137:20
gyp ERR! stack     at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\test\node_modules\xsl-transform\node_modules\node_xslt
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "xsl-transform"
npm ERR! node v0.12.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node_xslt@0.1.9 preinstall: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node_xslt@0.1.9 preinstall script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node_xslt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node_xslt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\test\npm-debug.log
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: A similar error also occurs on OS X 10.10

Comment: `C:\tools\pyhton2`. Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: Yes. it was installed via chocolatey. But this error also occurs on OS X 10.10.

Comment: Note the typo. Should probably be `python2`

Comment: I see your point. However all other packages that use python seem to work fine. And it doesn't explain why this also happens in OS X. Not only that, but there are many reports on node-gyp failing to build node_xslt.

Answer (score 0):

You can run below command to install windows dependency tools and try again.

npm install --global --production windows-build-tools